# How to add a breakpoint with Atom's node-debugger?

Tags: node.js, debugging, breakpoints, atom-editor, node-debugger

I'm trying to use the Atom's package 'node-debugger' ([here](https://atom.io/packages/node-debugger)), but I can't find a way to add a breakpoint to a file. I tried using F9 being at the line but it does nothing. Any idea?

I'm on Mac El Capitan and node 0.10.40

Answer (score 6):

You can use [atom-bugs](https://atom.io/packages/atom-bugs), I created it since I was looking for a better debugger for my favorite editor atom :) by the way node-debugger is a great tool but it does not satisfy my needs atom-bugs is more user friendly.

[atom-bugs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tQ2M.png)

Comment: atom node-debugger is currently broken for node 6.5, this alternative works finel and indeed is easy to use.  Take a look at the "getting started" issue at github

Comment: thank you sir @williams-medina, I'm using it and loving it so far :)

Answer (score -1):

I just use the debugger statement.

> debugger;;

Adding an extra ";" seem to help in some circumstances. :-)